# Visual studio 2008 IDE not rendering Custom Controls correctly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, custom-controls

I'm having an issue at design time with all my forms and custom controls within Visual Studios 2008. Up until the previous check in, all of the controls were rendering as expected. The only main difference between the current version and the previous working version was that a Property on the control `UIText` was renamed from `Content` to `Value`. The other changes are adding a new form and 3 new enums, but there's certainly no obvious change that would affect all forms in the program (including new ones).

All of the controls (on every form) now render as a box with the name of the control (however they all render correctly at run time):

[image: Rendering Issue]

I've tried creating a brand new form in my project, creating a brand new custom control with just a label on it, and I've still got exactly the same problem:

[image: Bizarre]

Note that standard .Net form controls work fine, so this is only an issue with custom controls.

If I restore my previous version from the repository, then everything starts rendering correctly again:

[image: Rendering Correctly]

I could just revert back to this working version and carry on, but I'd rather know how to fix the problem should it occur again. I'm posting here hoping it's a programming issue as apposed to a Visual Studios 2008 issue (on SP1 by the way).

### UPDATE - Issue traced, can't explain it

I *fixed* the issue. Well, fixed isn't really the right word for it. I located the issue by removing all of the user controls 1 at a time until the form started rendering properly again. The issue was in my Signature control (which has been present for ages, only in my latest check in I had added a reference to the project `iVirtualDocket.CodeLibrary` into the main project:

```
  iVirtualDocket
    - References iVirtualDocket.UIControls
    - References iVirtualDocket.CodeLibrary
  iVirtualDocket.UIControls
    -References iVirtualDocket.CodeLibrary
```

The signature has a property called `SignatureData`, which was doing this:

```
public byte[] SignatureData
{
    get
    {
        if (_signature == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return iVirtualDocket.CodeLibrary.Conversions.ImageToByteArray(
                _signature, ImageFormat.Png);
        }
    }
}
```

ImageToByteArray looks like the following:

```
public static byte[] ImageToByteArray(Image imageToConvert,
        ImageFormat formatOfImage)
{
    byte[] ret;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        imageToConvert.Save(ms, formatOfImage);
        ret = ms.ToArray();
    }

    return ret;
}
```

If I move the above method into the `UIControls` project, then everything works fine. However, as soon as I put the method back into the `CodeLibrary` project and call it there, all my forms stop rendering UserControls.

So doing the following fixes the problem, but I'd really like to know why:

```
public byte[] SignatureData
{
    get
    {
        if (_signature == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            // Need to call this code directly here instead of through 
            // the CodeLibrary conversions, otherwise all user controls stop 
            // rendering in design mode
            byte[] ret;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                _signature.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                ret = ms.ToArray();
            }

            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

*(What's even more bizarre is that I don't even use this property yet.)*

Comment: Try starting a second instance of VS, set break on all thrown exceptions.  Attach to first instance of VS.  Now load your project that displays the problem.  See if you catch any exceptions.

Comment: CodeLibrary.Conversions.ImageToByteArray isn't the same method as ConvertImageToByteArray.

Comment: @Phil - It is the same method, just a typo.

Comment: Ok, well ImageToByteArray doesn't check if imageToConvert is null.  If the VS designer is calling this method somehow behind the scenes, maybe that's the problem.  Check by attaching a debugger to VS.

Comment: No VS errors caught. Also, that's not it because **I do the null check in my property**.

Comment: I don't suppose you could post a complete (but cut down) solution that demonstrates the problem could you?

Comment: I'll be very interested in seeing a tear-down of this issue. It looks like an excellent corner case where the IDE doesn't perform as expected, best addressed by submitting a bug report to Microsoft.

Comment: I'll try and put together a repro ASAP.

Comment: I'm also curious about a repro. About the "What's even more bizarre is that I don't even use this property yet" it's not sure, if you didn't put any attribute on you property (like DesignerSerialization etc) + set localization it'll automatically be serialized in the resx, and will load the null value each time you load the control (even in design mode)

Comment: When it started working correctly, did you retry the previous approach without success again?

Comment: May be iVirtualDocket.CodeLibrary has some side effects like executing some code on module initializer or in static contstructor of `iVirtualDocket.CodeLibrary.Conversions`?

Comment: @Chibueze Opata - I can reproduce it consistently in my project. Unfortunately I cannot create a similar repro in a new solution.

Comment: Ok, I guess you should report to Microsoft just as @MrGomez suggested...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have an application that had similar non-design-time display problems.  By doing some research (and I don't remember exactly where we found it), we ended up creating a file

DesignTimeAttributes.xmta

Its type is that of "Design-Time Attribute File"

and in it, we just had to declare each of the control classes we had defined and qualified it as "DesktopCompatible".  This way it apparently tells the designer its ok to draw, and the actual functionality within some controls (also a signature control on a handheld scanner for us), would actually invoke something during runtime that was not available in the designer.  The content of the file was something like...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Classes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2004/03/SmartDevices/XMTA.xsd">
  <Class Name="MyNamespace.MyControl">
    <DesktopCompatible>true</DesktopCompatible>
  </Class>

  <Class Name="MyNamespace.MyOtherControl">
    <DesktopCompatible>true</DesktopCompatible>
  </Class>

  <Class Name="AnotherNamespace.MySignControl">
    <DesktopCompatible>true</DesktopCompatible>
  </Class>
</Classes>
```

This was also in addition to the comments provided csauve's answer.  If your constructor is trying to initialize something that is device dependent and thus throws an error because the design-time doesn't obviously have the device dlls, controls, or whatever could/would also kill that control at design time.  We've created two static functions to test either way via

```
public static bool IsDesignTime()
{
  return System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.UsageMode ==
         System.ComponentModel.LicenseUsageMode.Designtime;
}

public static bool IsRunTime()
{
  return System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.UsageMode ==
         System.ComponentModel.LicenseUsageMode.Runtime;
}
```

and call them respectively in the constructors...

Comment: I had the same problem again when using `DllImport`. All I had to do was create the DesignTimeAttributes.xmta file and doing this fixed it and the previous issue.

Comment: @DRapp, the xmta settings is fine, but the "LicenseManager" class is not available in .NET Compact Framework (.netcf). The project cannot be compiled. I will put another answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps you need to make your controls aware of when they are in design mode.   If avoidable, your control's parameterless constructor should not be performing any operations that are either expensive or have side effects (ie. loading a file from the disk).

I am assuming by your screenshots that you are using WPF.  I believe design mode can be determined using DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this)
see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerproperties.getisindesignmode.aspx

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
   public MyControl()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      if (!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
      {
        //Do expensive operations here
      }
   }
}
```

You may also want to have a read through http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgalasyn/archive/2007/10/29/troubleshooting-wpf-designer-load-failures.aspx

Comment: Hi, it's not WPF. It's WM6 (Compact Framework) in Visual Studios 2008. This isn't the issue, because as I said already the property isn't called (in my constructor or anywhere).

Comment: oh okay sorry I couldn't help

Answer (score 0):

When your designer side of your component(UserControl, Form, Component) cannot be rendered in Visual studio designer editor.
the easy way in add a "ClassDiagram" to the project, project context menu (right-click in the project name), View Class Diagram.
Editing Custom Attributes for the class (see fig.), automatically add entry in "DesignTimeAttributes.xmta", also we can set custom attributes for "Properties" too.
[image: ClassDiagram/xmta]
[image: Adding custom attributes to properties]

As I have commented above, the LicenseManager class is not disponible in 'NETCF'.
Then we can use the following:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace SmartDeviceCommon
{
    public static class SmartDeviceApplication
    {
        public static bool DesignTime
        {
            get
            {
                return Environment.OSVersion.Platform != PlatformID.WinCE;
            }
        }

        public static bool RunTime
        {
            get
            {
                return Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.WinCE;
            }
        }

        public static bool IsDesignTime()
        {
            // Determine if this instance is running against .NET Framework by using the MSCoreLib PublicKeyToken
            System.Reflection.Assembly mscorlibAssembly = typeof(int).Assembly;
            if ((mscorlibAssembly != null))
            {
                if (mscorlibAssembly.FullName.ToUpper().EndsWith("B77A5C561934E089"))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public static bool IsRunTime()
        {
            // Determine if this instance is running against .NET Compact Framework by using the MSCoreLib PublicKeyToken
            System.Reflection.Assembly mscorlibAssembly = typeof(int).Assembly;
            if ((mscorlibAssembly != null))
            {
                if (mscorlibAssembly.FullName.ToUpper().EndsWith("969DB8053D3322AC"))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

If not works, then use the **first comment of @Phil** :launch another instance of Visual studio with Admin rights, attach to the first instance, using the first instance, double click in your custom user control to the designer load, the un rendered component can contains platform specific calls (dllimport) or even another errors.

Last one you can clean the CoreCon folder in appData as in ("C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Microsoft\CoreCon\1.0"), change 'anton' to your user name.
(close the visual studio before that).

Hope this can help anyone, netcf is deprecated and lack of documentation

antonio