# Design Time Attributes File: Default Control size doubling

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile

I am developing a windows mobile application framework using .net Compact Framework 3.5 and have a BaseControls project that contains basic Custom Controls.  One of these controls is "TransparentLabel".  Since the .net CF eliminated alot of the functionality for design time properties, I have to use a DesignTimeAttributes.xmta file to specify default values for my control properties.

My problem occurs when setting a default size for my Controls.  Take my TransparentLabel for instance.  I set the default value using the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Classes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2004/03/SmartDevices/XMTA.xsd">
  <Class Name="BaseControls.TransparentLabel">
    <DesktopCompatible>true</DesktopCompatible>
    <ApplyDeviceDefaults>
      <PropertyName>Size</PropertyName>
      <ApplyDefaults>false</ApplyDefaults>
    </ApplyDeviceDefaults>
    <Property Name="Size">
      <DefaultValue>
        <Type>System.Drawing.Size, System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</Type>
        <Value>110, 20</Value>
      </DefaultValue>
    </Property>
  </Class>
  <Class Name="BaseControls.TransparentControlBase">
    <DesktopCompatible>true</DesktopCompatible>
  </Class>
</Classes>
```

However, when I drag and drop a TransparentLabel instance onto a form, the Size is doubled (i.e. 220x40).  I think this has something to do with the fact that I am developing my framework for VGA devices which has twice the resolution of QVGA devices, but I am not sure how to stop this.  I have tried setting the AutoScaleMode property on the destination form to Dpi and to None and that had no effect.  Now I realize I could just set the default value to half of what I actually want and it will be scaled to the desired size, but I want to understand what is causing this and how to stop it.

Much thanks in advance!

**Edit**
The following code shows the code generated in the designer file of a form when a TransparentLabel is dragged from the toolbox onto a form.  As you can see the Size is double what I specified in the Design Time attributes file.

```
        // 
        // transparentLabel1
        // 
        this.transparentLabel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 178);
        this.transparentLabel1.Name = "transparentLabel1";
        this.transparentLabel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(220, 40);
        this.transparentLabel1.TabIndex = 17;
        this.transparentLabel1.Text = "transparentLabel1";
        this.transparentLabel1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.TopLeft;
```

Comment: I am not sure if this helps, but .NET controls have a AutoResize property that has to be set to DPI to have the control resize automatically between VGA and QVGA for example. If you are drawing a custom control, you may have to use the DPI of the envrinment to rescale your control.

Comment: @Josef Do you mean the AutoScaleMode property of Forms?  I do not see a AutoResize property on either Controls or UserControls, and I have tried all possible values for the Form property AutoScaleMode (DPI, Inherit, None) with no effect.  I do not need my controls to autoscale between VGA and QVGA as we are only tageting VGA devices, but that did seem like a logic place to start seeing as how all my Controls seem to be scaled.

Comment: Sorry, AutoScaleMode is only available for forms. So please check the forms sale mode. I assume controls placed into form will inherit the setting. The online help for AutoScaleMode says it is a property of ContainerControl.

Comment: @Josef Your suggestion makes sense and was actually exactly what I was thinking.  The strange thing is, I have compiled my project with my Forms AutoScaleMode set to DPI and to None, and in both cases, when I dropped a custom control onto my form the size doubled what I specified in the Design Time Attributes file.

Comment: I am not sure how you design your control. I only know the way in VS by adding a custom control and then design it in visual mode in VS. What makes me nervous is your DesktopCompatible setting. I remember that custom controls may behave strange in Desktop design mode.

Comment: @josef The DesktopCompatible setting is to allow UserControls to continue rendering in the Form designer once a form starts using P/Invoke or Platform specific code like showing an input panel.  The following stack overflow post talks about this issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041878/visual-studio-2008-ide-not-rendering-custom-controls-correctly

Comment: @Josef Not dismissing your point, I greatly appreciate your input.  It is my understanding however that I don't really have a choice about using the DesktopCompatible attribute if I want designer support.